# Find the mean value in a list, and return the results score over mean value in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mean

A given list contains 3 elements for each record as below:

```
a_list = [('This is A.', 00, 2.0),
          ('This is B.', 01, 3.0),
          ('This is C.', 02, 3.0),
          ('This is D.', 03, 1.5)]
```

The result should produce only the records with the scores which equal or more than average value in third elements. The result should be like this:

```
result = [('This is B.', 01, 3.0),
          ('This is C.', 02, 3.0)]
```

Because the mean of third element in given list is `2.375`.
This is the attempt I've been trying and the error message, see below:

```
get_mean = np.mean(dict(a_list).values())
d = dict(a_list)
get_final = dict((x, y, z) for x, y, z in d.items() if z >= get_mean)
get_item = get_final.items()
get_result = sorted(get_item, reverse=True, key=lambda tup: tup[1])

return get_result


ErrorMsg --> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Comment: the error is coming from this call: `dict(a_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using list comprehensions:

```
mean = sum(x[2] for x in a_list)/len(a_list)
[x for x in a_list if x[2] >= mean]
```

Output:

```
[('This is B.', 1, 3.0), 
 ('This is C.', 2, 3.0)]
```

---

**Edit**:

The error you are getting comes from `dict(a_list)`. When creating a dictionary from a list of tuples, each tuple should have 2 elements `(key, value)`. It is not possible to create a dictionary with tuples of 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and explanation about the error.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
a_list = [('This is A.', '00', 2.0),
          ('This is B.', '01', 3.0),
          ('This is C.', '02', 3.0),
          ('This is D.', '03', 1.5)]
avg=float(sum(i[2] for i in a_list))/len(a_list)
res=[i for i in a_list if i[2]>=avg]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: `sum([i[2] for i in a_list])` can be replaced by `sum(i[2] for i in a_list)` :) Nice answer.